# Click event on input type 'radio' jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cannot assign an event to a radio button. I've googled this question and there were a lot of different solutions but nothing helps.

The last solution I tried was:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#monthly input[name=pricing-1]").click(function() {
    console.log("Test");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-round btn-outline-primary w-150 active">
        <input id="monthly" name="pricing-1" value="monthly" autocomplete="off" checked="" type="radio"> Monthly
      </label>
</div>
```

but nothing happens when I click on the button. What's wrong?

Comment: The name is `pricing-1` not `pricing1`

Comment: okay I fixed it and it still doesn't work!

Comment: use `$("input[name=pricing-1]")` or `$("#monthly")` not the both since it's the same element

Comment: Tried both and they didn't work then I found this approach on some website and it didn't work too

Comment: Ok, check my post with working snippet below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The main problem comes from the selector `#monthly input[name=pricing-1]` that will search for the input with name `pricing-1` that is a child of an element with the id `monthly`.

**Solution:**

You've to use `$("input[name=pricing-1]")` or `$("#monthly")` as selector since both refers to the same element :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#monthly").click(function() {
    console.log("Test 1");
  });
  $("input[name=pricing-1]").click(function() {
    console.log("Test 2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-round btn-outline-primary w-150 active">
        <input id="monthly" name="pricing-1" value="monthly" autocomplete="off" checked="" type="radio"> Monthly
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this what you're searching for @Desiigner ?

Comment: still doesn't work for me, trying to figure out why. When I press the button nothing happens. My problem might be caused by Django but everything else works perfect.

Comment: Did you get any error message in the console? are you sure the input wasn't added to the DOM dynamically?

Comment: No, just tried 'console.log' outside the function and everything works

Comment: we could try the event delegation instead check using : `$('body').on('click', '#monthly', function() {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180784/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-desiigner).

Answer (score 0):

Try this : add onclick="name_func" on your input

```
<input onclick="test()" id="monthly" name="pricing-1" value="monthly" autocomplete="off" checked="" type="radio"> Monthly
```

In your JS :

```
function test() { console.log("test"); }
```